# How to access a UITextField which is on a subview of a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone

i had a alertview with a textfield as a subview,,i want to submit gmail through this textfield with alertview button,but how can acess the textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm with `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement the below function in your class,

```
– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
– textFieldShouldClear:
– textFieldShouldReturn:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate methods to access the subviews of Alertview.